# "object not found" error when making forecast with a fitted "tslm" model

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, forecasting, lm

I am trying to implement leave-one-out cross-validation for my time series but got stumbled against a forecasting error.

```
library('forecast')

data_aero <- c(579, 624, 651, 687,  745,  753,  844,  965, 1076, 1078, 1107)
data_railway <-c(1417, 1507, 1696, 1831, 1985, 1506, 1854, 2059, 2104, 1932, 1778)


data.ts <- ts(data=data.frame(aero = data_aero, railway = data_railway),  start = 2004)

st <- 2003
limit <- 2013
en <- 2014

data.ts.train <- window(data.ts, start=st, end=limit)
data.ts.test  <- window(data.ts, start=limit+1, end=en)


m <- tslm(aero~railway, data=data.ts.train)
```

Till here everything is fine, but if I do

```
forecast(m, h=1)
```

I get an error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'railway' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `railway`, too:

```
forecast(m, h = 1, newdata = data.frame(railway = 1))
#     Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
#2014      -244.3887 -690.9415 202.1641 -981.6033 492.8259
```

If you make `k` step ahead forecast, you need to specify `k` new values for all covariates. In above, I have used `railway = 1` as an example.

Be aware, `forecast` is a generic function, with lots of methods:

```
methods(forecast)
# [1] forecast.ar          forecast.Arima       forecast.bats       
# [4] forecast.default*    forecast.ets         forecast.forecast*  
# [7] forecast.fracdiff    forecast.HoltWinters forecast.lm         
#[10] forecast.mlm*        forecast.mts*        forecast.nnetar     
#[13] forecast.stl         forecast.stlm        forecast.StructTS   
#[16] forecast.tbats       forecast.ts*         forecast.varest*
```

If you fit a "tslm", you have:

```
class(m)
# [1] "lm"
```

therefore, `forecast.lm` is called. It looks like you are pretty addicted to `forecast.Arima`, where only `h` needs be set. Have a read on `?forecast.lm`.

Comment: Impressive. Who could have thought. 

Yes indeed. I've tried a number of models, arima is one of them :-)

Question though: railway=1 means that railway needs to be forecasted as well, or it means that  the value "1" is being taken for the railway variable in forecasting?